# Data is not sent to a Kafka topic after aggregation using Flink (Pyflink)

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, pyflink

I'm working on a simple data aggregation example. It just groups by record ID and calculate average values over a tumbling window of 1 second.

1. generate source data using the flink faker connector with the Table api,
2. converts it into a data stream while assigning timestamps and watermarks
3. execute a process window function for aggregation, and
4. sink to a Kafka topic.

It works until the step 3 but records are not sent into the Kafka topic. It may be related to watermark assignment?

Could you please inform me how to fix it? Attached are the job status screen shot and source scripts.

[image]

Pyflink app

```py
import os
import time
from typing import Iterable, Tuple

from pyflink.common import Row, WatermarkStrategy
from pyflink.common.typeinfo import Types
from pyflink.common.watermark_strategy import TimestampAssigner
from pyflink.datastream import DataStream
from pyflink.datastream import StreamExecutionEnvironment, RuntimeExecutionMode
from pyflink.datastream.window import TumblingEventTimeWindows, Time
from pyflink.datastream.functions import ProcessWindowFunction
from pyflink.table import StreamTableEnvironment
from pyflink.datastream.connectors.kafka import (
    KafkaSink,
    KafkaRecordSerializationSchema,
    DeliveryGuarantee,
)
from pyflink.datastream.formats.json import JsonRowSerializationSchema

from models import SensorReading

RUNTIME_ENV = os.getenv("RUNTIME_ENV", "local")
BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS = os.getenv("BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS", "localhost:29092")


class AggreteProcessWindowFunction(ProcessWindowFunction):
    def process(
        self, key: str, context: ProcessWindowFunction.Context, elements: Iterable[Tuple[int, int]]
    ) -> Iterable[Row]:
        id, count, temperature = SensorReading.process_elements(elements)
        yield Row(
            id=id,
            timestamp=int(context.window().end),
            temperature=round(temperature / count, 2),
        )


def define_workflow(source_stream: DataStream):
    sensor_stream = (
        source_stream.key_by(lambda e: e[0])
        .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(1)))
        .process(AggreteProcessWindowFunction(), output_type=SensorReading.get_value_type())
    )
    return sensor_stream


if __name__ == "__main__":
    """
    ## local execution
    python src/c01_sensor_reading.py

    ## cluster execution
    docker exec jobmanager /opt/flink/bin/flink run \
        --python /tmp/src/c01_sensor_reading.py \
        --pyFiles file:///tmp/src/models.py \
        -d
    """

    env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
    env.set_runtime_mode(RuntimeExecutionMode.STREAMING)
    if RUNTIME_ENV == "local":
        CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        jar_files = ["flink-faker-0.5.3.jar", "flink-sql-connector-kafka-1.17.1.jar"]
        jar_paths = tuple(
            [f"file://{os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, 'jars', name)}" for name in jar_files]
        )
        print(jar_paths)
        env.add_jars(*jar_paths)

    t_env = StreamTableEnvironment.create(stream_execution_environment=env)
    t_env.execute_sql(
        """
        CREATE TABLE sensor_source (
            `id`      INT,
            `rand`    INT
        )
        WITH (
            'connector' = 'faker',
            'rows-per-second' = '10',
            'fields.id.expression' = '#{number.numberBetween ''0'',''20''}',
            'fields.rand.expression' = '#{number.numberBetween ''0'',''100''}'
        );
        """
    )

    class DefaultTimestampAssigner(TimestampAssigner):
        def extract_timestamp(self, value, record_timestamp):
            return int(time.time_ns() / 1000000)

    source_stream = t_env.to_append_stream(
        t_env.from_path("sensor_source"), Types.TUPLE([Types.INT(), Types.INT()])
    ).assign_timestamps_and_watermarks(
        WatermarkStrategy.for_monotonous_timestamps().with_timestamp_assigner(
            DefaultTimestampAssigner()
        )
    )

    sensor_sink = (
        KafkaSink.builder()
        .set_bootstrap_servers(BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS)
        .set_record_serializer(
            KafkaRecordSerializationSchema.builder()
            .set_topic("sensor-reading")
            .set_key_serialization_schema(
                JsonRowSerializationSchema.builder()
                .with_type_info(SensorReading.get_key_type())
                .build()
            )
            .set_value_serialization_schema(
                JsonRowSerializationSchema.builder()
                .with_type_info(SensorReading.get_value_type())
                .build()
            )
            .build()
        )
        .set_delivery_guarantee(DeliveryGuarantee.AT_LEAST_ONCE)
        .build()
    )

    # define_workflow(source_stream).print()  # it works!
    define_workflow(source_stream).sink_to(sensor_sink).name("sensor_sink").uid("sensor_sink")

    env.execute()
```

Data Model

```py
import dataclasses
from typing import Iterable, Tuple

from pyflink.common.typeinfo import Types


@dataclasses.dataclass
class SensorReading:
    id: str
    timestamp: int
    temperature: float

    @staticmethod
    def process_elements(elements: Iterable[Tuple[int, int]]):
        id, count, temperature = None, 0, 0
        for e in elements:
            next_id = f"sensor_{e[0]}"
            if id is not None:
                assert id == next_id
            id = next_id
            count += 1
            temperature += e[1] / 100 * 20
        return id, count, temperature

    @staticmethod
    def get_key_type():
        return Types.ROW_NAMED(
            field_names=["id"],
            field_types=[Types.STRING()],
        )

    @staticmethod
    def get_value_type():
        return Types.ROW_NAMED(
            field_names=["id", "timestamp", "temperature"],
            field_types=[Types.STRING(), Types.LONG(), Types.DOUBLE()],
        )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using event time windows, which requires watermarks. You'll have to specify a real WatermarkStrategy, not `WatermarkStrategy.no_watermarks()`.

It looks like the events should be in order (by time), so you can use
`WatermarkStrategy.for_monotonous_timestamps()` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works now. On top of the watermark strategy change, I had to make a couple of more changes. The updated working version can be found in the question section.